# Date filter wrong. Magento always converts the start/end date in a wrong format (UTC)

Tags: grid, filter, reports, date

If I pull up a sales report and filter shipped by 6/1/16 - 6/30/16 I get a weird result (doesn't match a 3rd party report). When I inspect the final sql query Magento sends to the database I noticed wrong dates:

> 2016-06-01 04:00:00' AND `sfo`.`created_at` <= '2016-06-30 04:00:00

but actually I was expecting

> 2016-06-01 00:00:00' AND `sfo`.`created_at` <= '2016-06-30 23:59:59

Debugging turned out this happens because Magento is calculating the dates on base of UTC time:

```
Mage_Core_Model_Locale -> const DEFAULT_TIMEZONE  = 'UTC';
```

This happens twice actually:

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Filter_Date::_convertDate()
Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Report_Collection::timeShift()
```

Why is Magento converting the date filter in a wrong format? Since its a constant value I can't have anything configured wrong in backend.

Anyone an idea? As always: Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the grid you can set the column type as: datetime instead of date as I think you have now.

Comment: Welcome on Magento SE. We encourage developed answers instead of one-liners. Please try and enhance your answer and give a bit more details.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code before the generating report, this will most probably solve the problem.

```
date_default_timezone_set(Mage::getStoreConfig('general/locale/timezone'));
```